# How to understand this fstab?

Tags: fstab

This is my fstab:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sat Jan 12 02:12:44 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=fb2b6c2e-a8d7-4855-b109-c9717264da8a /                       ext4    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        1 1
UUID=71362665-f627-41e1-a093-de42a0a356e2 /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
UUID=8024a5cd-af4b-4776-af0d-65ad80af8649 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
/dev/sdd1               /home4                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1               /home3                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1               /home2                  auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10,defaults        0 0
```

1. What is UUID=fb2b6c2e-a8d7-4855-b109-c9717264da8a? Is it a partition in sda?
2. What is tmpfs,devpts,sysfs, and proc?
3. What is /usr/tmpDSK?Is it /dev/sdb /dev/sda or what?

How do I get temporary directory in memory and then resort to disk when memory is full?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The UUID fb... is a partition. From the Information above, it is not
  possible to tell if it is /dev/sda or anything else.
- proc,sysfs,devpts are virtual file systems
- tmpfs is some ramdisk-like filesystem
- /usr/tmpDSK seems to be a file which is used as image to mount /tmp

Answer (score 5):

You can also find out which device and partition belong to the UUID by issuing the following as root:

```
blkid
```

or by issuing the following as a user

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```